# What is a container app in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

Our client wants us to make a container app, but I am not exactly sure what he means by this. I have to extend the functionality of his existing app but he does not wish to share his code with me.. so he says I should make a container app... I know it something similar to making in app purchases but can any one elaborate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** you should definitely clarify this with your client instead of this community.

I guess your client wants to have an *App-in-App* structure that you find in various iOS applications in the AppStore. E.g. the [three20 framework](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher) offers a launcher that is similar to the Springboard of the iPhone/iPad/iPod where you can put multiple apps (which aren't necessarily independent apps).

Comment: but three20 framework should already be present in the existing app right?